# How to install semantic-ui in desktop folder

Tags: npm, semantic-ui, npm-install

How to install semantic-ui in a folder like:

> (C:\Users\user1\Desktop\myproject)

I used this command but it doesn't work:

```
cd C:\Users\user1\Desktop\myproject
C:\Users\user1\Desktop\myproject npm install semantic-ui --save
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use instructions from http://semantic-ui.com/introduction/getting-started.html. Make sure you have both working npm and installed globally gulp.

Once you use `gulp build` you'll have option to specify your project folder. See the video on the linked above page, it shows what the installation process looks like.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.